# Why does defining MULTISITE true change the database connection in use

Tags: multisite, nginx

I have taken a copy of a multisite install to work on it locally. I've noticed that if I set define('MULTISITE', true); in wp-config, I get the standard database connection error. If I disable multisite, the theme loads but there are plugins missing.

Can anyone suggest what I have missed? Possibly relevant is that my local dev environment is using NGINX and the original is on Apache. I don't have anything specific to multisite in my nginx config.

If I set both of the following in wp-config:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
```

I get redirected to http://http//local.mydevsite/wp-signup.php?new=local.mysdevsite

I also get redirected there when trying `/wp-admin`

Comment: You say that you have taken a copy - can i assume that you updated the datebase connection constantes within **wp-config.php** so that the site is not still looking for the original database?

Comment: Yes,these have been changed to my local copy of the DB and confirmed as correct

Comment: Do you still have the `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` line in **wp-config.php** (above the lines in your question)?

Comment: I've tried with and without that commented. My understanding is that you don't need that line once multisite has been enabled for the first time.

Comment: You don't, I think it just adds the 'Networking' option to the **Tools** menu, but worth looking at.  I assume also that you've changed the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` constant to reflect the URI of your off-line copy (do not include `http://` or a trailing slash)?

Comment: Yes have also changed that - does not include http or trailing slash.

Comment: As it's only a copy anyway, how about removing the constants for multi-site (except `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE`) and trying to run the setup again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20861/discussion-between-codecowboy-and-david-gard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an error with the URLs that are defined in the multisite DB and/or a .htaccess issue.

When changing a regular WP install from live to local for example, you can change the URLs by setting this in your wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

However with multisite there are additional references to the URLs the multisite was set up on in the database. If on your local database you look in the tables `wp_blogs`, `wp_site` and `wp_options` there'll be entrys for the live site in the database. You need to change these to your new local url. i.e. from livesite.com to localsite.com

- In `wp_blogs` these are all the entries in the `domain` column
- In `wp_site` this is the entry under the `domain` column
- In `wp_options` this is the option_value corresponding to the option_name of `siteurl` and `home`

**Alternatively** for ease of setup and to minimise any changes to the database I would recommend that you keep the existing urls and just add a rule in your hosts file to root back to your local machine i.e. in your hosts have `livesite.com` root back to `127.0.0.1` that way your database doesn't have to change. The downside to this is that you'll have to remove the entry to view the live site and some people can find that confusing. So this is completely your choice.

You then need to ensure that your .htaccess has the correct setup for multisite and rewrites. Those settings can be [found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite) depending on if you have a sub domain setup or a sub folder setup.

Finally you need to make sure that on your local setup you have the rewrite_module active and your headers_module active (or equivilent) on your local web server